# Return Stripe Response within Firebase Function to Swift Application

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to make an iOS that connects to Stripe and can show user information and data and things.

I’m doing this by using Firebase Functions, so I don’t have to maintain a server, and also because I’m a newb to the extreme.

But when I try to say, get a customer by using the Firebase callable functions, ex.

```
exports.getCustomer = functions.callableFunctions((data, context) => { 
    stripe.customers.retrieve(
    data.customerID, function (err, customer) {
    console.log(‘customer’)
    });
});
```

I’m not sure where to place the “return” in order to actually use that ‘customer’ object in my app. I tried to stick a “return customer” under the console.log, but it’s never....... returning. I’ve also tried creating an empty string variable that I set after the console log and return, but that is always coming up as an empty string on the app.

Sorry for the typesetting issues, and this question is very theoretical - I’m typing on my phone because I don’t want to forget it and I’ll be away from my computer for a while.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I’d return the ‘customer’ object to my iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Promises), since the release of the Stripe node.js API version 2, they added support for promises: "Every resource method now returns a Promises/A+ compliant promise in addition to supporting the conventional callback".

So you could do as follows:

```
exports.getCustomer = functions.callableFunctions((data, context) => { 
    const stripeCustomerID = data.customerID;

    return stripe.customers.retrieve(stripeCustomerID)
    .then(customer => {
       return { customer: customer };
    })
    .catch(err => {
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError('<status error code>', 'xxxxxxx');
    });

});
```

As indicated in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors), have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError) for the possible values of